# How to get data out of react-hook-form?

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hook-form

I have these 2 functions for my form in react, the first one uses react-hook-form and gets me the data from the inputs fields seen below.

The second one makes an order to buy, i just need to get the data from the first one in the "order.buyer = {}"

Imports

```
import { useCartContext } from './../../context/CartContext';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
```

Functions

```
function Cart() {

  const { cartList, emptyCart, deleteItem, sumaTotal } = useCartContext();
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    
    console.log(data)
  }

  function generarOrden(data) {

      let orden = {}

      orden.buyer = (data);

      orden.total = sumaTotal();
      orden.date = new Date();

      orden.items = cartList.map(cartItem => {
        const id = cartItem.id
        const nombre = cartItem.name
        const precio = cartItem.price * cartItem.cantidad

        return {id, nombre, precio}
      })
    
    
      console.log(orden);
  }
```

Cart section + Form with inputs

```
  return (
    <>
      <div className='tables'>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Imagen</th>
              <th>Nombre</th>
              <th>Categoria</th>
              <th>Descripcion</th>
              <th>Cantidad</th>
              <th>Precio</th>
              <th>Total</th>
              <th>Eliminar</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          {cartList.map(prod => 
            <tr key={uuidv4()}>
              <td><img src={prod.imgSource} alt="foto" className='img-cart'/> </td>
              <td>{prod.name} </td>
              <td>Games</td>
              <td>{prod.desc} </td>
              <td>{prod.cantidad} </td>
              <td>${prod.price} </td>
              <td>${prod.price * prod.cantidad} </td>
              <td><Button className='button-card' onClick={()=>deleteItem(prod.id)}>Quitar Item</Button></td>
            </tr>
            )}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
        
      <div>
        <h4 className='cart-orden space'> Total de la compra: ${sumaTotal()} </h4>
        <Button onClick={emptyCart} className="button-card space">Empty Cart</Button>
        <Button onClick={generarOrden} className="button-card space">Generar Orden</Button>

        <form className='container-fluid bg-dark' onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label className="form-label">Name</label>
            <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder='Alejandro Otero' name='name' {...register('name', { required: true })}/>
          </div>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label className="form-label">Email</label>
            <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder='Example@gmail.com' name='email' {...register('email', { required: true })}/>
          </div>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label className="form-label">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="number" className="form-control" placeholder='11-4058-8867' name='phone' {...register('phone', { required: true })}/>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      
    </>
  )
}

export default Cart
```

Is a simply "problem" but im a complete noob with react/js so i cant find the way to give the data from onSubmit to generarOrden

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: Everything is working, but i need to get the Data from the "onSubmit()" function into the order.buyer {}, im a noob with react/js so im having trouble with that.

Comment: order.buyer = data

Comment: That doesnt work, order.buyer returns "SyntheticBaseEvent"

Comment: Can you show the entire component?

Comment: There! the complete component

Answer (score 2):

Use react-hook-form [getValues](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/getvalues)

Example:

```
const { register, handleSubmit, getValues } = useForm();

 <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => {
          const values = getValues(); // { test: "test-input", test1: "test1-input" }
          const singleValue = getValues("test"); // "test-input"
          const multipleValues = getValues(["test", "test1"]);
          // ["test-input", "test1-input"]
        }}
      >
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the watch function react hook provides. [Docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch)

And how you can use it for your use case is:

```
function getOrder(){
      let order = {
            buyer: watch("data"), # replace data with the name you need
            some: "other fields might go here",
         }
         # ....rest
   }
```